# Add to cart without refreshing using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I press the *add to cart* button, data should be inserted into the database and should be displayed immediately above the form without redirecting to the query page. In this code the first form is working correctly, but the next two forms which are duplicates of the first form are not working. The problem is that the next two forms, when submitted, get redirected to the query page. The index page code is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>fetch</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul></ul>
        <form action="userInfo.php" method="post" id="myform">
            name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
            age: <input type="text" name="age" /><br>

            <button id="sub">save</button>
        </form>

        <form action="userInfo.php" method="post" id="myform">
            name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
            age: <input type="text" name="age" /><br>

            <button id="sub">save</button>
        </form>

        <form action="userInfo.php" method="post" id="myform">
            name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
            age: <input type="text" name="age" /><br>

            <button id="sub">save</button>
        </form>

        <span id="result1"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/json/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/json/my_script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/json/my_script2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The query code is:

```
<?php 
include_once('http://loaclhost/json/conn.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('$name','$age')"))
    echo "successfully";
else
    echo "failed";
```

The JavaScript code is:

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
    $.post($("#myform").attr("action"),$("#myform :input").serializeArray(), function(info){$("#result1").html(info); });
    clearinput();
});

$("#myform").submit(function(){
    return false;
});

function clearinput()
{
    $("#myform :input").each(function(){
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

Comment: Where have you used AJAX? you are submiting the code to "userInfo.php". The page will compulsorily refresh.

Comment: Isnt it localhost? You mistyped it.

Comment: I am new to AJAX can you tell me what to do???

Answer (score 2):

You are submitting form by id : $("#myform").submit(function(){}
and the issue here is that you have given same ids for all the three forms here, make sure that each form will have different id.
also Button ids should be unique

Answer (score 0):

As @asim has mentioned duplicated ids are the problem.try following code.

working js fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/gw84j7hg/. (Using id selecters)

Updated fiddle using class selecters http://jsfiddle.net/gw84j7hg/2/

Form Code.

```
<form action="userInfo.php" method="post" id="myform" class="formSelecterClass">
                name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
                age: <input type="text" name="age" /><br>

                <button class="formSubmitButtonClass" id="sub">save</button>

            </form>


            <form action="userInfo.php" method="post" id="myform2"
     class="formSelecterClass" >
                name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
                age: <input type="text" name="age" /><br>

                <button class="formSubmitButtonClass" id="sub1">save</button>

            </form>


            <form action="userInfo.php" method="post" id="myform3"
         class="formSelecterClass">
                name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
                age: <input type="text" name="age" /><br>

                <button class="formSubmitButtonClass" id="sub2">save</button>

            </form>
            <span id="result1"></span>
```

JS Code

```
$(".formSubmitButtonClass").click(function(){

        $.post($(".formSelecterClass").attr("action"),$(".formSelecterClass :input").serializeArray(), function(info){$("#result1").html(info); });
        clearinput();
    });

    $(".formSelecterClass").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });

    function clearinput()
    {
        $(".formSelecterClass :input").each(function(){
            $(this).val('');
        });
    }
```

Comment: What if I don't know the number of forms because forms would be displaying through for each loop in php and number of forms  depend upon number of records in data base??

Comment: you can use a class selecter then..ill update the fiddle

Comment: You could add set class attribute for the both form and button when form is generated from loop.It will be better if you can avoid duplicated ids.

Answer (score -1):

ID on single HTML files can not repeated. If repeated, the first ID will work out and rest IDs will be invalid. That's why $("#myform") will only apply to the first form.